# Get last id from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, last-insert-id

I'm trying to get the last ID from MySQL and assign the value to string a.

I have a table `admin` with a adminID column.

```
 adminAPI api= new adminAPI();
                 try {
                    String id= api.selectLastID();
                    System.out.println(id);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

**adminAPI**

```
public String selectLastID() throws Exception  
    {
    String a;
    String sql="Select last_insert_id() as adminID from admin";
    DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
    Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
     while(rs.next()) 
     {  
          a= rs.getString("adminID");
         System.out.println(a);
     }
     ps.close();
     rs.close();
     conn.close();
     return null ;
 }
```

I suppose to get 1 since I have one ID in admin table.

Here the output I get

```
0
null
```

Thanks.

**DatabaseConnection**

```
package database;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DatabaseConnection {
     String driver;
     String dbName;
     String connectionURL;

     String username;
     String password;
     public DatabaseConnection()
     {
         driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
         connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
         dbName = "user";
         username = "root";
         password = "";
     }

     public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {

          Class.forName(driver);
          Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL+dbName,username,password);

          return connection;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
            try {
                Connection conn = db.getConnection();
                System.out.println("Database successfully connected!");
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: `select last_insert_id() as adminID` is enough. But last_insert_id() gives you the last inserted id. In your case, have you inserted it yet? last_insert_id() should be called right after you insert. If you haven't inserted it, you ll get 0.

Comment: @Tin I want to get the last ID from MySQL.  Am I using the wrong method ? (last_insert_id())

Comment: You're using the right method, but in order to get last id. You must insert something first. last_insert_id() is NOT giving you what's next auto increment id is. last_insert_id gives you what you insert it recently. In your case, you should insert admin table without giving id. Then if you wanna get admin id, you use last_insert_id to get that last inserted id.

Comment: @Tin if I just want to retrieve the ID, what should I change?

Comment: Check your database for existing rows in the table admin. Can you add the code of your DatabaseConnection class to your question?

Comment: @Al You can do like David suggested `select max(YOUR_AUTO_INCREMENT_COLUMN_NAME)+1 as adminID from admin`. Another way is you can do `select uuid_short()` will give you random generated id but this won't be sequential.

Comment: @Tin Do you know why I will getting null for String id ?   `String id= api.selectLastID();
                    System.out.println(id);`

Comment: @Touchstone I have edited my post

Comment: Your selectLastID() method always return null :( if you want it to return "id", do `return a;`

Comment: @Tin solved...thanks :)

Comment: @Touchstone solved, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get the last inserted, but you can get the greatest (I think is what you need):

```
Select max(columnId) as adminID from admin
```

Where 'id' is replaced with the name of the colum you are trying to get

You ususally use an id that increases, so the last id you have inserted is the greatest.

Comment: This is true only if you are the only one (i.e. DB connection) who inserts into the DB. If other connections insert simultaneously, then `max(id)` could be misleading.

Comment: I get  `Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'`

Comment: Lol, but you hace to replace id with the name of the column you are trying to get:

Select max("YOUR_COLUMN_NAME") as adminID from admin

Comment: This answer is wrong and could generate problems with concurrence. Don't use!

Comment: Read his question, he is not asking for an ID to insert, he only need the greatest.

Comment: You're right @DavidMarciel . Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

You can use function mysql_insert_id(). Take a look at this doc:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: FUNCTION user.mysql_insert_id does not exist

Comment: Maybe last_insert_id() is what Adrián meant. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id